# can not able to call spring controller using ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I am trying to call a spring controller using ajax, but can not able to go to the controller. I am getting Error 405 Request method 'POST' not supported error. I am keeping my code here please give suggestion to come over it

this is my ajax code calling controller from jsp page, here i am getting the anchor attribute value.

basic.jsp

```
function organizationData(anchor) {
    var value = anchor.getAttribute('value');  
    $.ajax({  
        url : "manageOrganization",   
        method : "GET",   
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {organizationId : value },    
        success : function(response) {  
            alert(response);   
         },  
         error : function(e) {  
          alert('Error: ' + e);   
         }  
    });
}
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/manageOrganization", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String organizationData(@RequestParam String organizationId) {
 return organizationId+"   associated";
}
```

here i should get the string to the jsp as a ajax response, but i am getting the error message. Any body can help me.

Regards Sree

Comment: Are you sure your `ajax` is setup with `GET`?

Comment: print your stacktrace....

Comment: I got this in firebug

<html><head><title>Error 405 Request method 'POST' not supported</title></head>
<body><h2>Error 405 Request method 'POST' not supported</h2></body>
</html>

Comment: i didn't get you Mr.  Sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/manageOrganization", method = RequestMethod.POST)....change to this

Comment: but in ajax call we have mentioned the mathod as GET, is it correct to rewrite in the controller as POST.

Comment: the same error is displaying in the firebug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For json response you need to add `@ResponseBody` annotation to your controller method.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `type:"GET"`  not `method:"GET"` try it like,

```
$.ajax({  
    url : "manageOrganization",   
    type : "GET",   // its type not method
    dataType: "json",
    .....
```

Read [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Also check that you are returning a `json` or not.

Comment: Controller is returning string

Comment: thanks you rohan, i got response from the controller. By changing the given suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is returning String which may be resolved into some other jsp file IF you have configured viewResolver in spring configuration file. Try adding @ResponseBody like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/manageOrganization", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String organizationData(@RequestParam String organizationId) {
 return organizationId+"   associated";
}
```

Comment: there is no view associated with the controller. I am just trying to get the response as string.

Comment: after changing "method" to "type", what is the error that you get?

Comment: thank you Mr.Florescent Ticker. I got the solution by changing it to the given suggestions.

Comment: I didn't get any error. Its going to the controller and gets string as the final output.